# Spring 4 @Autowired Morphia

Tags: spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired, morphia

How to autowire an instance of `Morphia` so I can have it injected instead of recreating it every time across all controllers?

```
@Controller
public class TeamController {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    @Autowired
    Morphia morphia;
    …
}
```

I found [this article](http://www.jayway.com/2011/12/07/autowiring-morphia-entities/) But I am getting an error using the code there. It seems odd to me that to inject such simple object to my controllers I  will have to extend  `AbstractEntityInterceptor` in all of them. Spring version is 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything special to make it work. Just do the following code to your configuration (I am assuming you are using Java Config, but if not the corresponding XML if easy to write):

```
@Bean
public Morphia morphia() {
   final Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
   //add mappings
   //add converters
   //whatever else
   return mophia;
}
```

You will now be able to use `@Autowired Morphia morphia` inside Spring Beans, including of course your `TeamController`.

The tutorial you are following is different because it shows how to inject `Morphia` into an entity which is not a Spring bean.

Comment: added a new class 
@Configuration
public class AppConfig { your code in it}   its working great.